# What exactly counts as a google map request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map application which i wish to deploy and while budgeting,i came across this page that outlines google maps premium features https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

and what the limits of the free tier consist. Since my app is a single page app,there wont be lots of pages with google maps,so loading many pages with embedded maps wont be the thing that gets me over free tier daily limit caps.

I do not have reverse geocoding with server with google. My app is a realtime movement plotter for a courier firm. In the case of my app,what consists as a request to google that can help me calculate the number of requests my app is going to make in a day?.

I am the only user of the app currently.

Comment: What APIs are you using?  What does your "map" code look like?

Comment: I am using ordinary markers. The app is similar to this http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html  The small difference is that i have lats and longs from a database pre-collected and stored. With time,upto 10 users will use the app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A map load is defined in the [documentation FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload):

> **How are map loads applied against the usage limits for Google Maps APIs for Web?**
>
> A single map load is charged when any of the following occur:
>
> - A web page or application displays a map using the Google Maps JavaScript API.
> - A web page or application displays a Google Street View Image API panorama using the Google Maps JavaScript API. If a Street View panorama replaces a map in the same div element, the panorama is not charged.
> - An application requests a single map image from the Google Static Maps API.
> - An application requests a single panorama image from the Google Street View Image API.
>
> After a web page or application loads a map, a static map image, or a Street View panorama, any user interactions with it, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads or affect usage limits.

Answer (score 3):

When you only use the Javascript-API(as it seems you do), the only thing that will count is the creation of a `google.maps.Map`-instance

**However, based on your description you should check if you application doesn't violate the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4):**

*No asset-tracking unless you have purchased the applicable Maps for Work license. Unless you have purchased an applicable Maps for Work license that expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Service or Content for commercial asset-tracking or in Maps API Implementations whose primary purpose is to assess vehicle insurance risks.*

- Commercial asset-tracking includes dispatch, fleet management, and Maps API Implementations that track your (or your end users’) assets (for example, private or commercial transportation applications, including taxi and vehicle-for-hire applications)

- Non-commercial asset-tracking implementations include applications used for a non-commercial purpose (for example, a free, publicly accessible Maps API Implementation that displays real-time public transit or other transportation status information or that allows end users to share real-time location with others).